# Does Forcecage automatically trap a creature in its area?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Force cage is a spell that allows you to create

> An immobile, invisible, cube-shaped prison composed of magical force springs into existence around an area you choose within range pg. 243 PHB

Which makes it seem as though I can just place it on top of any creature

and

> A creature inside the cage can’t leave it by nonmagical means.

**Does this mean the spell caster can imprison almost any medium sized creature for a whole hour without the creature getting the benefit of a Save first?**

It seems overpowered as almost any medium sized creature that cannot use magic or dimensional travel is almost guaranteed to be captured and even if it does if it has low Charisma and the spell caster casting this spell is a high level they almost have no means of escape. Am I reading this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**

You are reading this correctly. There is no saving throw if the subject is within the up to 20 ft/side area the cage appears to surround. Besides high level magic, shrinking or turning gaseous or whatnot(if the cage version), spells on the caster (if the cage version), you're looking at an hour of sitting still.

Comment: Just to clarify (and I'm sure you were being hyperbolic), there's nothing saying that someone trapped inside the box has to sit still for an hour. They can do lots of things while trapped, and even some things which affect those outside of the forcecage.

Comment: +1, but as [Darth Pseudonym points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/143626/24925), shrinking and *Gaseous Form* won't help you, because once you are shrunk or gaseous, your movement is nonmagical, and you "can’t leave it by nonmagical means"...