# Is escaping from a cage-shaped Forcecage really as ridiculously easy as it seems?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell [Forcecage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage) allows you to create a prison in the shape of either a cage with bars, or a closed box.

Escaping the Forcecage is (obviously) meant to be difficult:

> A creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means. If the creature tries to use teleportation or interplanar travel to leave the cage, it must first make a Charisma saving throw. On a success, the creature can use that magic to exit the cage. On a failure, the creature can't exit the cage and wastes the use of the spell or effect. The cage also extends into the Ethereal Plane, blocking ethereal travel.

However, if you choose the cage shape, it is ridiculously easy to escape, using one of the following means:

- [Wildshape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#ClassFeatures) into an form that can squeeze through 1/2 inch gaps
- [Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph), [True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph), [Mass Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-polymorph), [Shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange) or [Animal Shapes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-shapes), similar to Wildshape
- [Gaseous Form](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gaseous-form), can squeeze through any gap. Maybe also [Wind Walk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wind-walk), but that spell doesn't explicitly mention being able to squeeze through gaps.
- [Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field): Forcecage is only immune to Dispel Magic, not Antimagic Field. Would also work on a box-shaped Forcecage.
- [Disintegrate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disintegrate), which can destroy creations of magical force. Would also work on a box-shaped Forcecage.
- Casting [Misty Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) a bunch of times, since it's just a 2nd-level-spell and you're likely to suceed on the Charisma save eventually.

So, in the end, *Forcecage* with its cage shape seems like it's most likely a waste when used on a caster, especially a druid. Do note that *Antimagic Field* and *Disintegrate* are included not because they are especially easy, but for completeness, and to illustrate the wide variety of ways that one can escape a cage-Forcecage.

Is escaping from it really as ridiculously easy as it seems? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Disintegrate requires you see the invisible forcecage target, forcecage in box mode also blocks spells cast into the area, so I think you would need to be outside the forcecage if in box mode to disintegrate it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### It's not *easy*, but you can escape *quickly* if you have the right tools.

The phrase "a creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means" doesn't mean you can just turn yourself into a mouse/gas/etc and move out. Walking or flying are mundane movement, even if it was magic that gave you a fly speed or changed your physical size. Your method of leaving must itself be magical, which means it's basically going to be teleportation or planar travel, so you're up against the save. That excludes the "easy" methods of  *gaseous form* or wild shape, *polymorph*, etc. as escape routes.

Sure, you can spam *misty step* to get out sooner or later, but that does require you to know the spell (and have it prepared, if that's a thing for you), and potentially burn a bunch of spell slots and waste a bunch of turns, just to escape from one spell. I don't call that "easy". Simple, if you have the proper tools at hand, but costly. (I'm making that distinction in the same sense that walking up a mountain is simple, but not easy.) There are a number of "save or suck" effects that give you another try at the save every turn, but unlike *forcecage* most of them don't cost you spell slots every time you try.  But yes, trapping a powerful spellcaster inside a *forcecage* is probably not your best use of the spell.

*Antimagic field* is a sure-fire escape method, from inside or outside, but escaping a 7th level spell by casting a very specific 8th level spell is a very high cost indeed. You only get one 8th level spell per day, ever, so burning that merely to escape a *forcecage* is a hefty price -- and again, you have to have that AMF spell prepared already, or available through some other method, like a spell scroll.

*Disintegrate* seems like it would work in this case, whether the caster is inside or not. A *forcecage* is specifically a "prison composed of magical force", and *disintegrate* can target a "creation of magical force", so it's a valid target, and it "automatically disintegrates" a ten-foot cube out of a creation of force that's Large or larger. I can't see any reason a *disintegrate* spell would not work to open a hole in a *forcecage*. That said, again, you're defeating a 7th level spell with a specific 6th level spell, of which you only ever get 2 per day.  While it's not as uncommon as an *antimagic field*, it's still a significant cost that the party may not have access to. There are many such pairs of spells where one can specifically counter another.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108442/discussion-on-answer-by-darth-pseudonym-is-escaping-from-a-cage-shaped-forcecage).

Comment: I wonder if using Polymorph to turn into a huge beast would shunt you outside the cage then? The spell states you appear in the nearest unoccupied space that can accomodate your new size, so if you polymorph into a T-Rex, you don't fit in a 10 x 10 box anymore and get shunted out. Technically, you used magic to get out of the cage, and still requires a 5th level spell slot.

Comment: You have to see a target to disintegrate it. So that burns two slots for see invisible unless you can somehow work around that. Maybe blindsight or tremorsense count for "seeing" barriers. But those are weird and probably required a spell.slot to activate.

Comment: Certainly it's up to the DM to decide on that, but I would tend to waive the 'see' requirement if you can put a hand on it and feel exactly where it is.

Comment: The entirety of the first paragraph is not cited, and that is the main area of contention. By the rules here, it would seem you'd need to either cite a rule or real experience to cover it. It could easily be argued the intent is that a cage lets you cast spells or use ranged attacks at the imprisoned from outside the cage. but with the downside that it is much easier for the prisoner to escape if they have certain magical powers.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli I think that's only "When you cast the spell" otherwise I would employ the squeezing rules. If too large for squeeze shunting would then seem appropriate.

Comment: @SpiderWaffle under the DMG improvising damage rules (p.249) there is actually example damage for crushing that seem like they could apply in the "too big to squeeze" case, as a DM could interpret the "shunting" as being non-magical (it's really more of a placement/positioning rule), or at the very least against the intent of the cage effect to escape it by changing size.

Answer (score 12):

## It's only easy for a high level caster.

Besides that, most people just don't have the capacity to do much against it. If you're a fighter, maybe you've got a cloak of the mountebank that has one shot to try to teleport out. If your save fails, well you're done. Polymorph, as others have stated, won't help you because your means of escape isn't magical, you're using mundane movement, so it's the same as just hasting yourself and trying to walk out.

Forcecage is without a doubt one of the most powerful spells in 5E. You're forgetting that the most common enemy you're going to face isn't high level casters, but rather monsters. The spell will almost outright win you most monster encounters. 5E monsters aren't 3E monsters. Save for a number of exceptions you can count on one hand, they don't have extensive spell-casting capability. They're not tossing out disintegrate and most can't teleport. So that means you can effectively take a deadly encounter, forcecage half the opposition and make it a cakewalk and there's likely nothing the enemy can do about it. Honestly, it's one of the cheesiest spells in the game. If your DM doesn't specifically plan for it each and every major battle, it's essentially the "I win" button.

Granted, it's probably not the best spell for NPCs to use against players, but it's insanely good for the PC wizard against monsters and NPCs.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: My echo knight fighter will have no problems I think.

Answer (score -3):

## You're exactly right

Firstly, let's define what it means to escape from the force cage using magically means. This translates to you having used magic to facilitate the escape. So the two questions we need to ask ourselves is

1. Was magic actively used in the escape?
2. Was magic actually needed to make the escape possible?

If your answer was yes to both of these questions, the means of escape was magical. If your answer was no to either of these questions, the means of the escape was not magical.

Some other answers claim that "a creature inside the cage can't leave it by nonmagical means" translates to: that the means of escape have to seem magical to the players of the game in all context's. This however involves homebrewing what is considered to be magical because sage advice has already listed what is considered to be magical officially in-game. If you look at the *Sage Advice Compendium* under the monster section you'll find the question "Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?". The answer to this question states:

> Ask yourself these questions
>   about the feature:
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell
>     that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature
>   is magical.

So therefore using wildeshape counts as a magical means of escaping because:

1. The ability states: you can use your action to **magically** assume the shape of a beast that you have seen before (emphasis added)
2. You wouldn't be able to escape the forcecage without using this **magical** ability(emphasis added).

This same logic applies to all the other methods of escape you've listed because they are **spells** and are therefore **magical** based off sage advice (emphasis added).

From an RAI perspective I think the cage is supposed to be easier to escape from as well; given the mechanical benefits that its size is greater than the box's and that spells can pass through it (while they can't pass through the box). It also makes sense that enclosed cages with holes are easier to escape from than enclosed boxes that have no holes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108399/discussion-on-answer-by-gerson-lopez-is-escaping-from-a-cage-shaped-forcecage-re).